# platform independent symlinks in build script

Tags: windows, cygwin, gradle, symlink

I need to add to gradle build script a command that will create a symlink. I know that the person who builds that has cygwin installed. The problem is with export command. Here is what I got so far

```
    if(OS == 'win32') {
        exec { commandLine "C:\\cygwin\\bin\\mintty.exe", "--hold always", "/bin/bash", "-l", "-e", "export", "CYGWIN=winsymlinks", "&&",  "-e",  "ln", "-s", link, file}
        //exec { commandLine "cmd", "/c", "mklink", link, file}
        //exec { commandLine "export", "CYGWIN=winsymlinks" }
        //exec { commandLine "C:\\cygwin\\bin\\ln.exe" , "-s", link, file}
    }
    else {
        exec { commandLine "ln", "-s", link, file}
    }
```

Is there a standard way of doing it?

Comment: Standard way of doing what exactly? Is your solution working? A standard `ln -s` is not enough on cygwin?

Comment: creating symlinks under windows. The problem is that gradle starts `cmd` and I don't know how to use ln.exe to export link as a winsymlink or pass the command to mintty.exe.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Gradle starts cmd". It executes the exact command that you give it, without transforming it in any way.

Comment: so if I do `exec { commandLine...` gradle doesn't run it with windows command line? All in all I want to start cygwin from gradle script and then run `export CYGWIN=winsymlinks && ln -s x x`

Comment: It runs it as a normal external process. If you need a shell such as `cmd`, you'll have to start one yourself (i.e. `cmd` becomes the external process).

Answer (score 6):

The Ant builder, provided by every task has one. Seems like a solution, but as pointed out in the comments is not really cross platform:

```
task createLink << {  
   ant.symlink(resource: "file", link: "link")
}
```

Instead you could call the NIO API in Java, but you will need 1.7. Take a look at the 
[createSymbolicLink](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createSymbolicLink-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-)

Comment: This is NOT platform independent: `Execution failed for task ':createLink'.
> Could not launch ln: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "ln": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`. Of course if you have an `ln` from cygwin or other source on your `PATH` there's no problem.

Comment: Java NIO API is also not cross platform. As mentioned on their documentation "if your system supports symbolic links..."

Comment: @VicSeedoubleyew How is that not cross platform? If your system does not support symbolic links, then obviously you cannot create symbolic links on that system. It does not make the approach less cross-platform just because not all systems support symbolic links.

Comment: @smac89 well my answer above is an example of a workaround that is cross platform in that it also works on systems without symbolic links: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48359538/2873507

Answer (score 5):

Gradle doesn't offer a public API for creating symlinks. If your builds run under JDK 7 or higher, you could try the JDK's symlink API. Otherwise, it should be possible to solve this with `exec` as well, as long as you can figure out the correct command.

Comment: with "JDK's symlink API" I asssume you mean `nio.file.Files`?

Answer (score 1):

Example of `Files.createSymbolicLink` from `build.gradle`:

```java
File devDir = new File("${project.rootDir}/.dev")
File configDir = new File("${project.projectDir}/config")
Files.createSymbolicLink(devLink.toPath(), devDir.toPath())
```

Comment: This fails for me on windows (missing permissions), except when running gradle from an administrative prompt. I hate windows.

Comment: @fiffy Windows 10 Creators Update weakened restrictions for symlinks if you enable **Developer Mode**: https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2016/12/02/symlinks-windows-10/

Answer (score 0):

In the special case where your aim is to create a symlink to an executable file, there is a cross platform workaround, which is to create a shell script that will forward to the target :

#### File `forwarding_script_template`:

```
#! /bin/bash

_DIR_=$(dirname "$'{'BASH_SOURCE[0]'}'")

"$_DIR_/"{0} "$@"
```

#### In Gradle build file:

```
String templateScript = new File(projectDir, 
   "gradle/forwarding_script_template.sh").text;
String script = MessageFormat.format(templateScript, target);
writeFile(destination, script);
destination.setExecutable(true);
```

with the `writeFile` method equal to:

```
void writeFile(File destination, String content) {
       Writer writer = new FileWriter(destination);
       writer.write(content);
       writer.close();
}
```

Comment: Nice workaround, although "Cross platform" meaning anywhere you have `bash` is a bit restrictive. You still have to provide multiple templates for all platforms.

Comment: Thanks! Though now bash is on Windows too, it is true that adding another template for non bash environments could work

Comment: I know, I tried, but if I have to install something, might as well just install an executable called `ln` that's compatible with that `ant` command, a bit more lightweight. There are some Unix distros that don't have `bash` either, at one of my workplaces all the servers only had `zsh`. Btw, do you consider something cross-platform if the user of it has to configure their environment (set env, install, change registry/bashrc)? I always had the impression that people read it as "just works everywhere" (or at least on the 3 major OSs)

Comment: "everywhere" is an utopia, there is no way in this world that anything can work anywhere. Yes, it is true that most of the time, "cross platform" refers to Unix, Mac OS and Windows. It is up to you to decide whether this trick is good enough for you, by installing bash on Windows or not.